# How can the layout of a pageBlockSection be fixed in place so they don't move around when completed?

Tags: visualforce, dynamic-visualforce, html5

I have a pageBlockSection that moves/jumps up the screen when a value has been entered. How can I fix this and its contained inputField in place?

If I use the following, when the field is changed the section jumps upwards around half the field height.

```
       <apex:pageBlockSection title="Residential Postcode" columns="1" collapsible="false">
            <apex:inputText id="myField"
                            label="myField"
                            value="{!myField}"
                            size="12" maxlength="12">
                <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="sectionOne, sectionTwo" />
            </apex:inputText>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
```

If I use the following the label goes missing and the input field is left justified not

```
       <apex:pageBlockSection title="Residential Postcode" columns="1" collapsible="false">
            <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="sectionOne, sectionTwo" >
            <apex:inputText id="myField"
                            label="myField"
                            value="{!myField}"
                            size="12" maxlength="12" />
            </apex:actionSupport>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
```

Comment: Your second code sample is invalid and should cause compile errors. Your first version is the right way to do it. As for the field jumping around, I've never experienced that sort of behavior.

Comment: Another note, try to use the `<apex:pageBlockSectionItem>` tag

Comment: The compilation error was a typo introduced while sanitising/making a minimal example.  I've identified the issue and will post an answer for others momentarily.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved this issue and will share it so that others experience it. The issue seems to be caused by the action support generating different markup with the pageBlock on re-rendering, moving the action support outside the apex:pageBlockSection generate the same markup each time.

```
        <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="existingThings">
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Residential Postcode" columns="1" collapsible="false">
                <apex:inputText id="consumerPostcode"
                                label="Postcode"
                                value="{!consumerPostcode}"
                                size="12" maxlength="8" />
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:actionSupport>
```